# How should I end a letter asking for a big favour?

Tags: politesse, salutations, correspondance

I am writing a letter asking for a big favour*. I am looking for a phrase which could help me end the letter nicely. For example,

> That would be really helpful of you and apologies for this inconvenience.

<sub>* Asking my landlord to prepare a new contract (as my copy is lost) and send it from a different country.</sub>

EDIT2: What if the landlord is a young person (35 years) and has a less formal relationship with the tenant?

Comment: Context? What is the favour, who is the person you are writing to?

Comment: @Elena I added the context

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I do want to leave a comment about something you wrote in your question. If you've a less formal relationship with this person I would suggest that you refrain from saying "... and apologies for this inconvenience." I understand that you mean it, but this sounds way too formal and it sounds a bit too insincere. Just reword that last part. Even changing it slightly, to something like "I apologize for this inconvenience" can give off a much more sincere feeling.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for adding the context.

My suggestion would be : "Je vous remercie d'avance de votre compréhension et vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser de la gêne que j'ai pu vous causer/de la gêne occasionnée".

A bit formal but it won't hurt that you show some distance and respect for your landlord.

Answer (score 3):

I am a native French speaker, so I would write it like this. It is build on the answer given by Patrick Sebastien, but corrects the rythm of the sentence, so that it sounds better, and the ending is the traditional way to close a formal letter.

> Je vous remercie mille fois pour votre aide et votre compréhension, et vous
>   prie de m'excuser pour la gêne occasionnée. Dans l’attente d’une réponse 
>   favorable, je vous prie de recevoir, Monsieur, mes salutations les plus 
>   distinguées.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your landlord is male and you are male: (*if not, comment, and I will edit*)

> Merci beaucoup pour votre compréhension et pour
>   votre aide.  Je suis désolé si ma demande vous gêne. Dans l’attente d’une réponse 
>   favorable, je vous prie de
>   recevoir, Monsieur, mes salutations les meilleures.

This is in the formal, addressed to a male.

**It translates as:**

> Thank you vert much for your understanding and for your
>   help. I am sorry if my request inconveniences you. In waiting for a
>   favorable response, I pray that you receive, Sir, my best salutations.

It is a bit odd-sounding in English but it sounds good in French (or so I think). It is very formal and it is also quite polite.

Best of luck.

Comment: I quite like the tone and the wording, but why the odd *deux milles* ? *Je vous remercie mille fois* would be best I think.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Yeah that's a good point. I think I picked that up in a language course from a non-native speaker (who was a bit strange). Anytime I have said that, I have received a strange reaction haha. Will edit.

Comment: « je vous remercie mille fois » sonne mal et  est très peu utilisé en français, et quand ça l'est c'est familier. C'est calqué sur la formule italienne *grazie mille* qui dans sa langue d'origine est la formule de remerciements habituelle et polie, l'équivalent du français « merci infiniment » ou « merci beaucoup ».

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord avec @Laure. Il aurait du être simplement "merci beaucoup". J'ai jamais entendu "mille fois" sauf fait exprès.

Comment: @Laure Je l'ai mise à jour. Maintenant c'est "merci beaucoup".

Answer (score 2):

Je vous remercie pour votre aide et vous prie de m'excuser pour la gêne occasionnée. Dans l’attente d’une réponse favorable de votre part, je vous prie d'agréer, Monsieur, l'expression de mes salutations les plus distinguées.